# Inverting 5V switch with minimal amount of current drain

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches, signal

I want to invert a 5V switch. I = when 5v(switch closed) is applied to the input 0v is received out of the output. I know a transistor can be used by having the switch short circuit the gate and this is what I've used. A small amount of current still flows when the switch is closed as its a short across the switch. I want to know the best possible way to reduce the amount of current used.

Edit: [image: Photo of circuit]Added photo

Comment: This is very unclear. What is a "5V switch"? What is the "it" in this sentence: "A small amount of current still flows when the switch is closed as its a short across the switch." Please provide a schematic showing the circuit you already have, using a transistor.

Comment: One component: 74HCT04. Consumes uA.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Added a photo. I know a resistor can be between added switch and ground to limit current but then resistor at the base of the transistor needs to be increased which can only be increased so much.

Comment: That’s quite a different story. A 74HCT04 and a MOSFET.

Comment: Can you rewire the LED so that you can switch the low side? Then you don't need an inverter at all.

Comment: Note that "BrakeLight" implies *vehicle*, and vehicles are notorious for having noisy and poorly-regulated electrical power.  If using a transistor this way, it's max voltage rating will have to be at least 2x the peak voltage that could ever be experienced.  When I was young, I used a 2N3906 (rated for 40V, should be enough right?) in an automobile ignition-switch circuit. It worked for 2yrs before burning up (and almost taking the auto and garage with it.)  Always use a fuse!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand but if you want a function to turn off the Led when switch is closed use one of solution bottom.

Btw, dont use so high impedance (like 100k) to supply the switch. Its resistance can be too high (dusted or oxidated contacts) so it affects the voltage drop on switch and couse an incorrect function.

[image]